# Route 53 failover routing takes downtime of 6 to 8 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-route53, failover

I am getting "502 bad gateway error" between switching regions of Route 53 Failover.

Switching between primary to secondary takes 2-3 minutes if primary is down. 
Meanwhile when on DR site IF primary comes up It will takes another 6 to 8 minutes for redirecting traffic from DR to primary. How to completely minimizes downtime from 6 to 8 minutes to 0?

Comment: Please note Primary and Dr are in different regions and have 3 EC2 instances each running in ASG behing ELB

Comment: I assume you are relying on some sort of health check/s (ELB > R53 or R53 only) to determine if to failover or not? Can you share the health checks (one for each region) configuration? are they configured the same?
Downtime will never be 0 by the way.

Comment: Yes I am relying on Route 53 Health check for Production and DR Site

Comment: Yes I am relying on Route 53 Health check for Production and DR Site Prod_Health_Check points to main domain name whereas Another HealthCheck points to ELB of Primary region. It works well when Primary goes down and then up (or while on DR Dr goes down then up), Problem of 502 Bad gateway occurs during switch over regions ie Primary to DR 2 to 3 minute and DR to primary 6 to 8 minutes. I am Ok for seconds but not minutes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check how long it takes your ELB Health Check + Route53 Health Checks to determine a failover is required, the final step is the TTL of the DNS records.

For example, let's say you have a web application, hosted behind and ELB, and you are accessing it via myapp.mydomain.com.

#### ELB Health Check

While the primary thing you should check is the R53 health check (see below), the ELB configuration is also important.

Look at how long it should take to determine failure:

- HealthCheck Interval - The amount of time between health checks
- Unhealthy Threshold - How many failed health checks

**Make sure this configuration is the same in ELBs in both regions.**

#### Route53 Health Check

This is the main thing that will determine how long failover takes.
You probably have 2 CNAME records for myapp.mydomain.com, each pointing to a R53 health check, and each health check points at an ELB at it's respective region.
Check both health checks and make sure:

- Request interval - How often R53 will poll your ELB for it's health.
- Failure threshold - The number of consecutive health checks that an endpoint must pass or fail for the status to change.

**Make sure both health check's config (Primary and Secondary) are the same.**

Once the status changes, it's up to the DNS record TTL.

#### Route53 CNAME TTL

Check how long your CNAMES will point to a record after a failover by looking at the record TTL. For example, if TTL is 30, it will take approx. 30 seconds for Route53 to start pointing to the secondary region.

**Make sure both CNAME records have the same TTL.**

After following this you can determine how long it should take to failover, for example:
Your health checks are looking at port 80:/ availability, your health checks take approx. 30 seconds,  and your apache dies on the primary site.

Within 30 (example) seconds ELB will determine instances out of service and stop forwarding traffic.
Within the same 30 (example) seconds the R53 health check which is monitoring the same healthcheck (port 80:/) will also determine primary ELB is unhealthy.

**This is where R53 decides to start pointing DNS queries to your secondary ELB.**

If your TTL is set to 30, failover should be completed in approx. 1 minute, +/- some time for propagation, etc.

Make sure not to set your health checks to be too frequent, depending on how many instances are behind your ELB, it can result in a lot of calls to your service from the ELB and Route53 for the health endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for brief descriptive answer @Eytan, What you have mentioned over here is about CNAME, But I am using A Record which points to ELB of respective regions i.e, Primary and DR. As you said configuration for both ELB are exactly same in terms of Healthcheck, and Unhealthy threshold, Point is downtime of few minutes ie Primary to DR 2 minutes and that too DR to Primary If comes up is 6 to 8 minutes. We are laready using F5 load balancers which does the same in fraction of seconds, and client is expecting the same during Cloud Migration. Downtime in seconds is acceptable but not in minutes.

Comment: In case of ELB health-check is concerned There is no issue to mark those instances as healthy and ELB is able to detect same immediately, in both Primary and DR region. But in case of Route 53 same thing takes time in minutes during switch-overs Route53 not able to balance the same within seconds.

Comment: You should never use an ELB's IP address - AWS may change the IP when the ELB scales in and out, you should only use the DNS FQDN of the ELB which you may wrap with a CNAME